# Report viewer web part is not loading data in report viewer in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, reporting-services, report-viewer

Report viewer web part is not loading data in report viewer. Here is the error I found in browser console:

> "Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: id"

Comment: does it work fine in powerbi service what all components are included in the report is there any custom component used ex. from 3rd party appsource?

Comment: It works fine in ReportServer Browser i have not used any custom component

Answer (score 0):

Change a browser to check if the issue still exists.

Turn off the debug mode in the Web.config file of the SharePoint site then compare the result:

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
```

In addition, Report Viewer web part cannot be used on modern pages within SharePoint.